# Javascript : Issue with "for loop" and ("name")[i]

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I tried to apply styles to each li elements of holder

Html :

```
<ul id="holder">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript :

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById("holder").getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)
{
  document.getElementById("holder").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].style.bottom = "-100%";
}
```

It "seems" to work but `("li")[i]` is considered as an error... and it breaks all the rest...

Issue : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**

I tried many ways but I always get this error, is it normal or am I missing something?

*PS: This is my first post, if I do it wrong please tell me instead just removing what I wrote, I'm not evil, I wont turn your forum into a garbage and I understand the rules but english isn't my every day language and forums are unknown to me... I will do mistakes but I need advice, explanations, patience... thank you.*

Comment: cant you indent your code?

Comment: I recommend storing the `li` elements in an array before hand. giving your code `var children = document.getELementById('holder').getElementsByTagName('li');` and you can then just refer to them as `children[i]` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: [**here is aworking fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bawfpjte/) with your code.

Comment: Use the SO snippet editor so your sample code is runnable.

Comment: Really horribly inefficient code.  If there are 10 `#holder li` tags, you are doing 40 separate DOM queries instead of 1 with `querySelectorAll("#holder li")` and then store and reference that result from then on.

Comment: I put the code into a snippet editor and I don't get an error, with just a `<ul><li>list</li></ul>` (omitted items for brevity).

Comment: @Jhecht : u omited the `holder` for brevity? :)

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, ul* was the holder.

Comment: Thanks for the quickness ^^" jfriend00 can you give an example of your solution, I've never seen it before and it seems very interesting in my case, I have a lot of li...

Comment: The error message, please. The code in the post doesn't cause any errors.

Comment: Teemu : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: `gEBTN()` returns a live list of elements. If you're removing elements (not in the code though), the list is updated accordingly.

Comment: Ok jfriend00, with you solution my error is gone, thanks to all of us my problem is solved :D

Comment: Now, about closing the topic and the answer, what I have  to do ?  Don't forget, FIRST POST ! xD

Comment: How do I set jriend00's answer as the best I found ? Please ^^"